# Nodejs not able to run when i move the routes and model to different folders

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run the serverjs in nodejs by separating the routes and models in different folders, but I am getting the below mentioned error where as i can run the same without moving them to different folders.

```
Error: Cannot find module '../models/catModel'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rajesh/app4/routes/catRoute.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rajesh/app4/cat_server.js:14:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
```

Source Code:

/app4/cat_server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cats');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var cats = require('../routes/catRoute')(app);
var server = app.listen(3000, function(){ console.log('Sever runnign at localhost:3000'); });
```

/app4/routes/catRoute.js

```
var _= require('lodash');
var Cat= require('../models/catModel');
module.exports = function(app) {
    /*Create*/
    app.post('/cat', function(req, res){
        var newCat = new Cat(req.body);
        newCat.save(function(err){
            if(err){ res.json({info: "error during creating of cat create", error:err}); };
            res.json({info: 'Cat created successfully'});
        });
    });
}
```

/app4/models/catModel.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var catSchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: String, age: Number, type: String });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Cat', catSchema);
```

Comment: You need to post your express code.

Comment: /app4/cat_server.js                                                                                                  var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cats');


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true
}));

var cats = require('../routes/catRoute')(app);

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log('Sever runnign at http://localhost:3000');
});

Comment: /app4/routes/catRoute.js                                         var _= require('lodash');
var Cat= require('../models/catModel');

module.exports = function(app) {

 /*Create*/
 app.post('/cat', function(req, res){
 var newCat = new Cat(req.body);
  newCat.save(function(err){
   if(err){
    res.json({info: "error during creating of cat create", error:err});
   };
   res.json({info: 'Cat created successfully'});
  });
 });
}

Comment: /app4/models/catModel.js    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var catSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 name: String,
 age: Number,
 type: String

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cat', catSchema);

Comment: Please let me know if you need any further information @RobertMoskal

Comment: Rewrite your question!!! No one will read your code in the comments!

Comment: i updated code in my question itself robert moskal, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something doesn't look right with the relative path loading.

Given that `/app4/routes/catRoute.js` is being loaded correctly with a path of `../routes/catRoute`, I suspect that doing the following will help:

```
var Cat = require('../../models/catModel');
```

Comment: no luck same response:( rajesh@rajesh-ThinkPad-T420:~/app4$ node cat_server.js 
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../models/catModel'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rajesh/app4/routes/catRoute.js:2:10)

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when path is not right for server

Try this

```
var Cat = require(process.cwd() + '/models/catModel');
```

Comment: Still the same error but the path was coming correctly.module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/rajesh/app4/models/catModel'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rajesh/app4/routes/catRoute.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved, the issue is with my catModel.js file has an additional extension, once I updated its working as expected. Thanks for all your help.